# XQuery node-name() function, how is it work?

Tags: function, xquery

I want add additional pairs for each `pair`.
I have this kind of code:

```
<data>
<pair>
    <key>keyName1</key>
    <value>something1</value>
</pair>
<pair>
    <key>keyName2</key>
    <value>something2</value>
</pair>
<pair>
    <key>keyName3</key>
    <value>
            <listOfPairs>
                <pair>
                    <key>keyName4</key>
                    <value>Something6</value>
                </pair>
            </listOfPairs>
    </value>
</pair>
<pair>
    <key>keyName5</key>
    <value>Something9</value>
</pair>
</data>
```

and I need insert other pairs after each pair no matter in which level, with prefix: "copy" with different value:

```
<data>
<pair>
    <key>keyName1</key>
    <value>something1</value>
</pair>
<pair>
    <key>copy_keyName1</key>
    <value>another1</value>
</pair>
<pair>
    <key>keyName2</key>
    <value>something2</value>
</pair>
<pair>
    <key>copy_keyName2</key>
    <value>another2</value>
</pair>
<pair>
    <key>keyNamedwithLists</key>
    <value>
        <listOfPairs>
            <pair>
                <key>keyName4</key>
                <value>Something6</value>
            </pair>
            <pair>
                <key>copy_keyName4</key>
                <value>Another6</value>
            </pair>
        </listOfPairs>
    </value>
</pair>
<pair>
    <key>keyName5</key>
    <value>Something9</value>
</pair>
<pair>
    <key>copy_keyName5</key>
    <value>another9</value>
</pair>
</data>
```

For this kind of result to get, i need to use function:  `node-name()`? How does it work? How I should use it? Ore maybe I should use another function?

Comment: `node-name()` returns the element name. For `<foo/>/node-name()` it will return `foo`. I don't see why you'd needed it here, as you only need to access values, not element names.

Answer (score 1):

As @jens-erat mentioned, you don't need `node-name()`, instead presumably you want something like this:

```
<data> {
for $pair in /data/pair
return
    ($pair,
    <pair>
        <key>{concat("copy_", $pair/key)}</key>
        <value>some other value</value>
    </pair>)
}</data>
```

UPDATE - As you mentioned in your comment, that will only copy the outer-most pairs, if you want to copy all pairs no matter their depth, then you need to use a recursive descent to transform the input.

I actually found writing this in XQuery for your particular use case quite a challenge, although the solution is rather elegant I think :-) I would be interested if anyone else can think of a better implementation?

```
xquery version "1.0";

declare function local:copy-pair($pair as element(pair), $copying) as element(pair)+ {
    (
        if(not($copying))then
            $pair
        else(),
        <pair>
            <key>{concat("copy_", $pair/key)}</key>
                { local:recursive-descent($pair/key/following-sibling::node(), true()) }
            </pair>
    )
};

declare function local:recursive-descent($nodes, $copying) {
    for $node in $nodes
    return
        (
        typeswitch($node)
            case element(pair) return
                local:copy-pair($node, $copying)

            case element() return
                element {node-name($node)} {
                    local:recursive-descent($node/node(), $copying)
                }

            case text() return
                if($copying and $node/parent::value and empty($node/parent::value/element()))then
                    text { concat("SOME NEW VALUE. old value = ", $node) }
                else
                    $node

            default return
                (
                    $node,
                    local:recursive-descent($node/node(), false())
                )
        )
};

local:recursive-descent(/data, false())
```

The `recursive-descent` function basically does a left-to-right recursive-descent through the node tree. Any element named `pair` it passes of to the `copy-pair` function, otherwise it just copies everything apart from when we have a copy (`$copying`) of a text node within a `value` element, in this instance it creates a new alternative text value for the copy.

The `copy-pair` function determines whether to copy the original pair depending on if we are already copying or not and then creates the new copy of the original pair, it then itself performs a recursive descent.

Comment: looks okay, but when I put my map, I get that pair at data/pair[key= "keyNamedwithLists"]/value/listOfPairs/pair this one doesn't get any copy. 
I need that ultimate path, which takes no matter waht paths is till any of pairs. Every pair should get a COPY. (Addition: given map is dynamic and changes every time.) According to your answer he will add additiona pairs only to those: /data/pair

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to [XQuery update](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/#id-transform) and the transform expression you can do something like:

```
declare function local:additional-pairs($d){
 copy $c:=$d
 modify(
   for $p in $c//pair[not(.//pair)] (: pairs with no descendant pairs :)  
   return insert node 
    <pair>
      <key>copy_{$p/key/string()}</key>
      <value>some new</value>
    </pair> 
   after $p
  )
  return $c
};
```

Comment: You also need to account for children of pair where the value is a list of pairs, possibly you just need a predicate on $c//pair

Comment: Thanks Adam, I made that change. In the example keyName3 is not copied (although the keyname becomes keyNamedwithLists?) In your code it is.